# Spliting of string in substrings of specified length

Tags: string, matlab, split

What i have is an array containing strings of length = 31. Total number of strings = 13700. I want to split all strings into substrings of length 5,22 and 4. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I thought of using strsplit but it needs a delimiter instead of a specified length.So basically i am confuse.

Comment: What do you mean "length 5,22 and 4"? And "split all strings": do you mean "split the combined string"?

Comment: @LuisMendo length of a string is 32. So i want to split that into substrings of length 5,22 and 4.

Comment: Just tell me how to split one string, i will use for loop for splitting others.

Answer (score 3):

With fixed-length strings and fixed-length substrings it's *really* easy. If they're not already, mash the strings around until they're in a 2-D char array, one string per row (`cell2mat()` will be your friend if they're currently in a cell array), and split:

```
s1 = s(:, 1:5);
s2 = s(:, 6:27);
s3 = s(:, 28:31);
```